# Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

**When I clone the project from GitHub and execute the program it throws this error**

***Please help all thanks***

[image]

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 61

Answer (score 1):

If you run `flutter doctor`, you probably will see:

```
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/118502 seems to be the latest issue in which this crops up. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106674 notes they reverted a buggy [change](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/119244), but it hasn't hit stable yet, so you'll have to symlink the bundled JRE folder as a workaround til the next AS update.

e.g. for mac, you can use:

```
cd /Applications/AndroidStudio.app/Contents
ln -s jbr jre
```

Comment: ln: jre: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1):

For Mac:

Go to finder and find Android studio:

right click and click show package contents
Create a new folder called jre
copy the contents of the jbr folder and paste them into jre folder
reload your terminal and type flutter doctor

For Windows:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
then copy the content of jbr and paste the content into jre folder
run doctor again and problem solved

Answer (score 0):

"Unsupported class file major version 61" indicates java 17, which is used by Gradle.

> https://stackabuse.com/bytes/fix-java-error-unsupported-class-file-major-version-63/

This indicates major class version and corresponding Java versions.

> https://docs.gradle.org/7.3/release-notes.html

Per this link, Java 17 support was added circa Gradle 7.3, so either upgrade to a more recent version of Gradle, or change your settings to use an earlier version of Java (such as `JAVA_HOME` if using the CLI).

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem running a test code as part of udemy course from GitHub repo [mi_card_flutter](https://github.com/londonappbrewery/mi_card_flutter)

As you can see, my flutter version is 3.16.9

```
flutter --version
Flutter 3.16.9 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
```

And my dart version is 3.2.6

```
  dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.2.6 (stable) (Wed Jan 24 13:41:58 2024 +0000) on "macos_x64"
```

The problem was the repo was using older version of gradle wrapper which is `gradle-7.0.2-all.zip` so upgraded it to use `gradle-7.5-all.zip`

This change is needed in the `gradle-wrapper.properties`

How I found this version is supported? When I create a new Flutter project in my Android Studio it uses the same version.