# how i solve this error in flutter after update android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWJo5.png)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\Users\Roshan Bhagwan Jena\AndroidStudioProjects\untitled1\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\Roshan Bhagwan Jena\.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 61

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

i try so many so many ideas but working after that i uninstall android studio and reinstall it but not run my app.

Comment: Do the ideas presented in these links help?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75294524/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings-file-flutter and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343735/could-not-open-settings-generic-class-cache-for-settings